# Approximately complemented subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, approximation-theory

**Definition:**
Suppose $E$ is a subspace of normed space $X$. Then $E$ is approximately complemented in $X$ if for any compact subset $K$ of $E$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there is a continuous linear operator $P\colon X\to E$ such that $\|x-P(x)\|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$.

**Question**: Is there any subspace of a Hilbert space which is not approximately complemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. That is, any subspace $E$ of a Hilbert space $X$ is approximately complemented. Indeed, take any compact subset $K$ of $E$ and any real $\epsilon>0$.
Let points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $K$ form an $\epsilon/2$-net of $K$, and then let $P$ be the orthogonal projector from $X$ onto the linear span of $x_1,\dots,x_n$, so that $P$ is a continuous linear operator of norm $\le1$, which may be considered as a map from the Hilbert space $X$ to $E$. Take now any $x\in K$. Then $\|x-x_i\|<\epsilon/2$ for some $i=1,\dots,n$. Hence,
$$\|x-Px\|\le\|x-x_i\|+\|x_i-Px_i\|+\|P(x_i-x)\|<
\epsilon/2+0+\epsilon/2=\epsilon. $$

Answer (score 3):

Iosif Pinelis has given a direct argument, but if you are studying approximate complementation in more general Banach spaces then the following argument might be of interest.

In Zhang's original paper ([Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 127 (1999), 3237-3242](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-11/S0002-9939-99-04896-0/))  he remarks that if $E$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and $E$ has the approximation property then it is approximately complemented in $X$. Although the approximation property does not always pass to subspaces, when $X$ is a Hilbert space $E$ is also a Hilbert space and hence $E$ will have the approximation property.

Comment: Probably the OP did not want to assume that the subspace is closed.  If the subspace of the Hilbert space is closed you can just use the orthogonal projection onto it.

Comment: Is there a non closed subspace of some Banach space s.t. that it is not approximately complement but the closure of the subspace is approximately complemented?

Comment: @BillJohnson oh, of course, good point. I just checked Zhang's paper more carefully and it seems that when he says "subspace" he really does mean "linear subspace" rather than "closed linear subspace".

Comment: @BillJohnson good question, I don't know, and I suspect no one has looked at this before